# Get Realtime Database nodeID from Cloud Function trigger ref create in Golang

Tags: go, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have my cloud function deployed like this:

```
# Must call go vendor as go modules are ignored
go mod vendor
yes Y | gcloud functions deploy ${name} \
    --trigger-event providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.create \
    --trigger-resource projects/_/instances/${databaseInstance}/refs/${referenceNode}/{nodeId} \
    --region ${region} \
    --runtime go113 \
    --allow-unauthenticated
```

From the following code, how can I get the `nodeId` value?

```
// RTDBEvent is the payload of a RTDB event.
type RTDBEvent struct {
    Data  interface{} `json:"data"`
    Delta interface{} `json:"delta"`
}

// OnRealTimeDatabaseCreate prints information about a RealTime Database event.
func OnRealTimeDatabaseCreate(ctx context.Context, e RTDBEvent) error {
    // my code
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the variable `nodeID` from the object path.

Try access the metadata value, [source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/functions/console_snippets/firebase_rtdb/firebase_rtdb.go)

```golang
    meta, err := metadata.FromContext(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("metadata.FromContext: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Function triggered by change to: %v", meta.Resource)
    log.Printf("%+v", e)
    return nil
```

Comment: Thanks but this is Firestore, Not Realtime :/